# sfdisk - partition creation problem

Tags: linux, partition, dd, fdisk

I'm trying to create disk image with 2 partitions:
First partition: 1Mb for boot and second partition of the maximum capacity

```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.img bs=1M count=10
  /sbin/sfdisk flash.img -uM << SFDISK_EOF
,1,L,*
,,L;
SFDISK_EOF
```

I got an error:

```
sfdisk: I don't like these partitions - nothing changed.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm working with CentOS

Comment: Might be simplest to use regular `fdisk` to partition the image once manually, and then use `sfdisk -uM -d` to dump the partition info into a file or standard output. The dumped output may highlight a critical error in your commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use something more user-friendly like cfdisk? It's not really supposed to be used outside of a script.

Comment: the cfdisk is not part of the CentOS distribution, this is the reason why I'm using sfdisk.
Anyway, I increased image size and problem is gone...